# ( Autohotkey )Storing WinTitle into Multiple Variable and WinActivate one of the title using the Stored Variables

Tags: autohotkey

i need some help.

So i want to get WINTITLE from multiple excel windows and store them into multiple variables, then activate the preferred window using WINACTIVATE WINTITLE whenever i want. It would likely be like this :

(when 1st Excel file is open ) :
WinGetTitle, 1st, A ;storing 1st title to "1st" variable

;when 2nd Excel file is open
WinGetTitle, 2nd, A ;storing 2nd title to "2nd" variable

;when 3rd Excel ifle is open
Win GetTItle, 3rd, A ; storing 3nd title to "2nd" variable

(when i want to activate 1 of the window)
WinActivate, 1st or 2nd or 3rd ; activate 1 of the title

But the problem is, i only able to activate the 1st window.

So what should i do? can somebody help me with this please? Thankyou very much

Comment: Could you show us what you've written so far that only activates the 1st window?

Answer (score 0):

See example at the bottom of this post https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/10/autohotkey-winlistbox.html